# cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile google test

Tags: c++, cygwin, googletest, platformio

I have read a few topics about errors: cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to program.exe.stackdump

But I can't find something that fits my situation.

This is my project: https://github.com/InzynierDomu/LED_tester

I got error in UT:

```
Building...
Testing...
[==========] Running 9 tests from 3 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
      0 [main] program 751 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to program.exe.stackdump
0 [main] program 751 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to program.exe.stackdump
[----------] 3 tests from PWM_controller_test
[ RUN      ] PWM_controller_test.active
[       OK ] PWM_controller_test.active (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] PWM_controller_test.set_pwm_up
================================================================================================================================================================================= [FAILED]
```

I have very similar test in test/native/Color_tester_controller_test and test/native/PWM_controller_test. The first one works properly, the second not with that test.

```
TEST_F(PWM_controller_test, set_pwm_up)
{
  EXPECT_CALL(hal_mock, set_PWM_output(1));
  EXPECT_CALL(view_mock, update_duty());
  uut.keyboar_reaction(Cursor_move::up);
}
```

I stack, and maybe anyone has some idea?

EDIT:
It's only Cygwin gcc problem, on MinGW gcc it's work fine /:

Comment: Sounds like a memory corruption issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837874/cygwin-exception-open-stack-dump-file

Comment: @Ari I have read this topic, but doesn't any example fit this /: I try to expand memory for Cygwin but it doesn't work. Allocating memory as done before the mentioned test in the same way as before in the earlier test as it fixture work. in the first case, it works, in the next case it does not /:

Comment: Normally, I would compile with address sanitizer (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhpzDFvXopk) which can catch memory bugs, but I'm not sure if address sanitizer works on Cygwin.

Comment: Nice tool, but not for my setup ): Now I thinking about destructors in my uut. Because in normal work controller responsible for deleting view (pass there by pointer). In testing fixture, controller deletes view and fixture try also delete that after each test?